# Script for existing search bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, searchbar

I have tried the adding the Google search to my existing search bar to power it with no luck. Then I tried another bit of Javascript I found on the forums here and did place it directly after the form. Here is the existing code, but I do not have it working yet. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse right" id="search-not-mobile">
                <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#search">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle search</span>
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
```

```
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

        </span>
              </div> 
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler like this one (w/ your own selectors):

```js
$('button').click(function(ev){
    location.href="search.html?q=":$("[type=text]").val();
});
```

Then, create `search.html` with a normal Google search box.

Comment: Thank you so much Leo. I am afraid I may be in a little over my head. I am unsure of how to modify with my own selectors.

Comment: @Deborah However, the code will work if the elements provided in your question are the only `button` and text input on the page

Comment: Thanks @Leo, Good resource. Not my first visit there-lol. I will work on it, as I want to maintain the style and animation function. I will report back